# Is "yesterday night" acceptable?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, time

I catch a lot of grief about this from family and friends, so I figured I'd settle the score once and for all.

In verbal context (though not written), I tend to use the phrase

> ... yesterday night...

rather than *last night*. Is this grammatically correct, regardless of how uncommon it might be?

Comment: I'd vote for the archaic "yesternight" myself...why have "yesterday" and "yesteryear" survived, but not "yesternight"?  While we're at it, let's have "yesterweek", "yestermonth", "yesterevening"...

Comment: @PSU: yesterfebruary? Or we could just use a word like "last"?

Comment: @MrHen:  Of course, "last" is the way we'd really go.  But I'm going to keep "yesterfebruary", and thanks for it.

Comment: @PSU: Fair enough. And I must admit that words such as "yesterlunch" sound really awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it's incorrect strictly speaking, but it triggers some cognitive dissonance because "yesterday" implies *day* rather than night. Just say "last night" already. ;)

Comment: By that logic "yesterday morning" should have the same effect, correct?

Comment: if only logic had anything to do with languages :P

Comment: @user6223: Well... morning is part of day. :)

Comment: Yes, tbh I don't care about the semantics or grammar of it, it's just wrong. :)

Comment: I’d argue one could say “yesterday evening” without implying daytime…

Comment: @Brian Nixon: And you'd be right.

Comment: @KellyCHess What do you mean by *already* at the end of your response?

Answer (score 9):

This **is** grammatically correct, indeed, assuming:

1. You are using it as an adverbial adjunct, as in *Yesterday night I went to the movies*.
2. You believe the word *yesterday* is a noun (as in *Yesterday is over.*) functioning as an adjective (just like with *yesterday morning*).

Then, *yesterday night* is a valid noun phrase, however awkward. In fact, I find it pretty common! :D

Answer (score 2):

I'd say overall that *yesterday night* sounds nonstandard, but I checked for it in the corpus, and found that it is attested, and even in professional-sounding contexts; see the following quote (from a newscast):

> Tomorrow is the funeral of the late Prime Minister. From a legal point of view, Mr. Peres is, as of **yesterday night**, acting Prime Minister. There is a take-care government. The President will call on the president, on Mr. Peres within a few days to establish a new government, with the real shock an earthquake of grief that we all feel here, there is and must be stability in the political system.

Here *yesterday night* seems just as good as *last night*, though I couldn't say exactly why (Rabin was assassinated in the evening).

Why not start using **yestreen**?

Comment: Certainly ***yestereve*** and ***yestermorn*** both exist, or at least, did so once upon a time under the fresh-fallen snows of yesteryear. OED citations: “§1859 Tennyson *Marr. Geraint* 702 ― And yester-eve I would not tell you of it, But kept it for a sweet surprise at morn. 
§1864 W. C. Bryant Italy 39 ― Slaves but yester-eve were they-Freeman with the dawning day.” There was also ***yestern***, meaning “of yesterday” and functioning as both adjective and adverb. OED citation: “1891 Ld. Houghton Stray Verses 85, ― I linger on the oaken bridge Fine-filigreed with yestern snow.”

Answer (score 1):

"Last night" is more specific but I don't think anyone would object to calling "tonight" part of "today."

> (At night) What did you do today?
>
> (At night) What day is it today?

However, you certainly wouldn't say "today night" instead of "tonight."

I checked my local dictionary for a definition of "yesterday": `the day before today`.

My guess is that "day" here implies a 24 hour period. That period includes a night and saying "yesterday night" provides an unambiguous reference to a specific time.

All of that being said, "last night" sounds better and takes less time to type and write. The only reason I can see for saying it is to bug your friends which, in my opinion, isn't good enough.

Answer (score -1):

In and of itself, *day* encompasses the whole day. Usage makes it seem as if it applies to only the sunlit part of the day. To make "yesterday night" more seamless, *yesternight* might be the better choice. Just hand anyone who objects a dictionary.

Answer (score -2):

Well, as per generally accepted English semantics, **yesterday night** is not correct. 
In strict grammatic sense, it may not be incorrect, but as far as usage in both verbal or written context is concerned, **last night** is the only correct form

Comment: Usage rather than isoformal patterning is usually taken to be the measure of acceptability. 'Twilight' is of course a noun referring to a time during the day; 'Just a song at twilight' would probably be quite acceptable to most critics. However, I'd mark **Yesterday twilight, the fridge broke down.** as being incorrect.

Answer (score -2):

Its not acceptable in English. Refer this :

http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/26212-yesterday-night-ok.html